# Erlang crash dump memory data inconsistency in processes

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, crash-dumps, erl

We have an erlang application that crashed due to memory issue:

```
Thu Jun  9 13:22:19 202
Slogan: eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 3936326656 bytes of memory (of type "heap").
System version: Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.1.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:48:48] [ds:48:48:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]
Compiled: Mon Oct 12 07:40:16 2020
```

The total memory in =memory section of the crash dump says:

```
=memory
total: 126190588240
processes: 99882909648
processes_used: 99879758664
system: 26307678592
atom: 6308969
atom_used: 6281592
binary: 221919896
```

but when I total the processes' memory in the =proc section, it turns out to be 24660309644 bytes which is way less than the above mentioned for processes_used i.e 99879758664 bytes.

Can anyone help me understand why and where could this difference be?